# How do I replicate PHP's PRNG algorithm implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, php, random

I've created a procedural image generator that uses the default pseudo-random number generator built in PHP5.

I can set the seed with `mt_srand($id);` and get always the same numbers sequence (with `mt_rand(0,255);`).

---

#### What I need:

a PRNG implementation that will work the exact same way in PHP and C#

---

**Example:**

*PHP:*

```php
mt_srand(123);
echo mt_rand(0,255); //returns 34
echo mt_rand(0,255); //returns 102
echo mt_rand(0,255); //returns 57
echo mt_rand(0,255); //returns 212
echo mt_rand(0,255); //returns 183
```

*C#:*

```c#
setSeed(123);
print getRand(0,255); //returns 34
print getRand(0,255); //returns 102
print getRand(0,255); //returns 57
print getRand(0,255); //returns 212
print getRand(0,255); //returns 183
```

( ^ function names are not referring to existing ones, named just for example's sake )

Comment: Any given platform or API is free to implement their own PRNG as they like, and of course the exact sequence of numbers will depend on specific implementation choices. I don't know if there is even a standard PHP implementation. For sure, .NET's implementation (which is used in your C# code) is not guaranteed to be the same across different versions of .NET.

Comment: The only way for you to reliably guarantee separate processes are using the same PRNG is to include your own implementation in your code. If you want help with that, do some research, make an attempt, and ask a _specific_ question if you run into problems. Be sure to include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The `mt_` stands for Mersenne Twister. Ciacco, have you tried replicating the values using [a C# implementation of Mersenne Twister](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5147/A-C-Mersenne-Twister-class)?

Comment: Little hint: PHP seems to use an implementation compatible with the one from Dave Wagner, e.g. found at https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~noi/tasks/2010/PKMATCH/MersenneTwister.h

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, I tried! But as you pointed out there are different implementations which will return different results. Thanks for your help, I'll try to implement it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the tips!

I resolved my problem implementing a custom PRNG algorithm by myself both in C# and PHP.

Since I needed it soon and didn't have time to go through the whole Mersenne Twister theory and the incompatibilities of the two languages (like different behaviors of types and operators...) I decided to write a really simple PRNG algorithm:

**C#**

Code:

```cs
using System;

public class CiaccoRandom
{
    private static int tree=0;

    public void plantSeed(int seed)
    {
        tree = Math.Abs(seed) % 9999999+1;
        getRand(0, 9999999);
    }

    public int getRand(int min, int max)
    {
        tree = (tree*125)%2796203;
        return tree%(max-min+1)+min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
int seed = 123;
int min = 0;
int max = 255;
CiaccoRandom randomer = new CiaccoRandom();
randomer.plantSeed(seed);
randomer.getRand(min, max); // returns a pseudo-random int
```

---

**PHP**

Code:

```php
namespace ciacco_twister;
class CiaccoRandom {
    private static $tree = 0;

    public static function plantSeed($seed) {
        self::$tree = abs(intval($seed)) % 9999999+1;
        self::getRand();
    }

    public static function getRand($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        self::$tree = (self::$tree * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$tree % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
require_once "ciacco_twister.php";
use ciacco_twister\CiaccoRandom;
$seed = 123;
$min = 0;
$max = 255;
CiaccoRandom::plantSeed($seed);
CiaccoRandom::getRand($min,$max); // returns a pseudo-random int
```

---

**Notes:**

I needed a PRNG that, given a seed and an int range, would always return the same sequence of int numbers both in PHP and C#.

It's pretty limited but it serves its purpose!

Maybe it will be useful to someone else...